# Adding users to wordpress database from android app

Tags: android, wordpress

I am making an android app to connect to a website built in wordpress. I am trying to figure out how I can add users to the wordpress database through the app itself.

So the user can register through the app. Plus other functionalities.

So far I've tried writing my own PHP scripts that use predefined Wordpress functions such as [register_new_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_new_user/) etc. However this doesn't seem like the best approach.

For example, when using [username_exists()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/username_exists/), after including several required files, I am running into issue where a certain global variable is missing.

Is there any plugin or API that does what I am looking for? I've already looked at these resources but they don't serve the purpose. Or maybe they do, but I don't know how to use them.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/json-api

So if anyone is familiar with how to set this up, or can point me in the right direction, it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
The error I get when running this php file:

```
<?php

//database connection here, code now shown

if ( username_exists( $_GET['username'] ) )
           echo "Username In Use!";
       else
           echo "Username Not In Use!";
?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /home2/extrovee/public_html/wp-includes/cache.php on line 123

The source of the error at line 123 in [cache.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/cache.php) is

```
function wp_cache_get( $key, $group = '', $force = false, &$found = null ) {
            global $wp_object_cache;

            return $wp_object_cache->get( $key, $group, $force, $found ); //<--line 123
    }
```

So do I need to assign $wp_object_cache in my php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As obvious as it may seem, the only thing I had to do was adding the line below, to set up the WordPress environment.

```
require_once('wp-load.php');
```

Now this isn't the recommended way of doing it, unless you are building something for your own site (unlike a plugin) as in my case.

For a better approach on setting up the WP environment, read this article:
http://glennmessersmith.com/pages/wpenviro.html

Answer (score 3):

The API given at https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/ is a REST API.

First of all, you will use OAUTH2 https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/ to 'log in' to the site.

Then you can 'call' the REST API.

Such as using 'GET' to get: `www.YOURSITE.com/wordpess/rest/v1.1/me` to get the meta-data about your user account.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/me/

GET/POST/DELETE/UPDATE are [HTTP methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

There are libraries such as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) that will assist you in connecting to REST APIs (and even with OAUTH), but you would need java POJOs that match the REST API. Then you would need to annotate your POJOs properly.

Or you can manually do it through an HTTP connection (not recommended, since this can be tedious/error prone) (Though for a 'simple' example such as only adding a user to WP... it might work fine)

---

Edit to answer comment below:

Apparently you can call the function: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user

And if you want to create a user with more info you use this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

To use the above two, I'm guessing that you'd have to be logged in with a user that is 'allowed' to create new users.

You might(probably will) have to create a public PHP file in your WP directory that allows you to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to use the API and OAUTH2. I'm not familiar with Retrofit and POJOs, but I can read up on that. 
However I don't see a method for adding an user to WP, on the api link, unless I am missing sometihng. So how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry, missed what you were asking for then, I looked at the API and don't see any way to 'add' new users. However, there IS PHP functions that you can call to do that(listed above). If you make new php files within your WP dir. you can probably hit those from your Android App fairly easily. (with Oauth, etc. if you don't want people to be able to register themselves)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I tried wp_insert_user() and got the error as with username_exists(). I have added some more details to my original post if that can help solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From within your Android app, you may simply point user to http:///wp-login.php?action=register for the user to register a new account.

Comment: I don't want the user to leave the app and enter the browser, if that's what you mean.